# Improper indentation in converting ruby hash to yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, erb

I am trying to convert ruby hash object to YAML format using YAML.dump(obj) but I am getting improper indentation even after using dump options.

I have below executable ruby script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "yaml"
require "erb"

context_path = ARGV[0]
context = YAML.load_file(context_path)['context']

def get_yaml(obj)
  YAML.dump( obj['imports']['external_repositories']['credentials'] ).sub(/.*?\n/,'')
end
```

The value of - `obj['imports']['external_repositories']['credentials']` is

`{"iacbox"=>{"basic"=>{"name"=>"", "password"=>""}}, "nexus"=>{"basic"=>{"name"=>"cpreader", "password"=>"swordfish"}}}`

Note : I used the sub method to remove "---" at the start of the output

The ERB template calls the above get_yaml method as :

```
credentials:
   <%= get_yaml( context ) %>
```

The output that is coming is :

```
credentials:
iacbox:
  basic:
    name: ''
    password: ''
nexus:
  basic:
    name: cpreader
    password: swordfish
```

while I am expecting the output as :

```
credentials:
  iacbox:
    basic:
      name: ''
      password: ''
  nexus:
    basic:
      name: cpreader
      password: swordfish
```

How can I get the expected output from a dump?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When asking a question, make it direct and about programming. Asking if someone can help you can often be answered by yes or no (and it is a question about someones abilities, not about programming). A good way to start is "How do I ..."  You also should make your problem more simple `obj['imports']['external_repositories']['credentials']` is a detail from your original encounter of the problem, but doesn't make your question more clear. Simplifying an issue to a **minimal** case to reproduce it, often helps with finding the problem, and it certainly makes it easier for others

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest thing for you to do here is just put the credentials key also in the Hash, i.e. change your template snippet so that it is one line:

```
<%= get_yaml( context ) %>
```

And change your get_yaml method to be:

```rb
def get_yaml(obj)
  YAML.dump({'credentials' => obj['imports']['external_repositories']['credentials']})
    .sub(/.*?\n/,'')
end
```

If that doesn't work for you, for example, if you have additional keys underneath the credentials key that you haven't mentioned, you could also do something like this:

```rb
def get_yaml(obj)
  YAML.dump(obj['imports']['external_repositories']['credentials'])
    .sub(/^---\n/,'')
    .gsub(/\n/m,"\n  ")
end
```

Where `gsub(/\n/m,"\n  ")` replaces all newlines with a newline plus two spaces.